# How to take two inputs in one line separated by space in python

Tags: python-3.x, input, valueerror

So I am practicing in hacker earth and I have to take two inputs in a single line separated by space.
The below code is what I used:

```
 x, y = [x for x in input("Enter two value: ").split()]
```

It is supposed to take input that looks like '2 5'

And it is returning an error:

> Execution failed
> ValueError : not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) 
>
> Stack Trace:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/tmp/165461120/user_code.py", line 13, in 
> x, y = [x for x in input("Enter two value: ").split()]
> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

What I think I understood is that it is giving two values as a single string. If so how do I take separate them and convert them into integers?

Comment: This is working. Are you sure you did not typ an extra space after 5 (like '2 5 ' ?). Other than that, no need for the comprehension on this code: the return of `.split()` is already a list - as far as you type the correct number of elements, the values will be assigned to the variables as expeded in: `x,  y = input("...").split()`

Comment: If you typed a tab between the 2 and the 5 on the input line you would get that exact error. Just try again and type the space :)

Answer (score 1):

To take two inputs

```
x, y = input("Enter two value: ").split()
```

This should do the trick. To convert to int you can do it seprately on the both x and y.

Or better way is to use a map function

```
x, y = map(int, input().split())
```

Comment: I tried like that as well but it was not working. It shows the error expected 2 but got 1

Comment: Do you have a special character for split, since you mentioned hacker earth, you can check the inputs format provided there.

Else you can get the values as single input and print it, so you can understand the format then you can split it as required.

Comment: @karthikeyan what do you mean by a special character to split?? and how do I check the input format??

Comment: I guess you must not be having 2 inputs, you can verify it by typing

print(input("Enter two value: "))

Note : This code cannot be submitted

Answer (score 0):

For your case, only typecasting is remaining, so that splitted numbers becomes `int`. So, just you have to add

`x, y = [int(x) for x in input("Enter two value: ").split()]`

Alternatively, For taking 2 inputs in single line, you can use `map` also

`x, y = map(int, input().split())`

Comment: When I am typecasting it's showing "invalid literal for int() with base 10"

Comment: @KarthikBhandary, Can you share the code where you tried to typecast the numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because Hacker Earth, in almost all cases, gives its input line by line.
In almost all cases, the inputs are of the form below.

```
1
2 3 4
5
6 7 8
```

This will differ on problem by problem basis and needs to be personalized for each problem.
You are getting the error *not enough values to unpack* because Hacker Earth is giving only a single input, and you are expecting 2. If it had been more than 2, then the error would have been too many values to unpack.

In all probability its because you are trying to input the number of test cases, which is the first input, and a single number input, in most hacker earth problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Process-01 : using list comprehension**

```
whole_line = input() # 1 2 3 4 5
strings = whole_line.split(' ') # ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
# remove extra space within numbers if any from list
numbers = [int(num) for num in strings if len(num)>0]  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(numbers) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now you can write down the whole logic within one line like below

```
numbers = [ int(num) for num in input().split(' ') if len(num)>0 ]
print(numbers)
```

**Process-02 : using filter and map function**

```
whole_line = input() # 1 2 3 4 5
strings = whole_line.split(' ') # ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
# remove extra space within numbers  if any from list
strings = list(filter(lambda x :len(x)>0 ,strings))
numbers = list(map(int,strings)) # convert each string to int
print(numbers) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now you can write down the whole logic within one line like below

```
numbers = list(map(int,filter(lambda x : len(x)>0,input().split(' '))))
print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as the code for inputting in one line separated by space in python

```
N,X = input("").split()
```

If you trying for a number, use this instead:

```
N,X = input("").split()
N=int(N)
X=int(X)
```

Answer (score -1):

In [20]: a,b = raw_input().split()
12 12.2

In [21]: a = int(a)
Out[21]: 12

In [22]: b = float(b)
Out[22]: 12.2
You can't do this in a one-liner (or at least not without some super duper extra hackz0r skills -- or semicolons), but python is not made for one-liners.